# How to turn off startup text of GNU gdb in XCode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm new to XCode 3.1.2 and Objective-C 2.0. I've just discovered using breakpoints for logging instead of littering the code with millions of NSLog() statements. The problem is, when the debugger starts up it spews half a screen full of status and credits info into the console.

**Is there any way to suppress this text?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XCode debugger is a front end to GDB. If Xcode lets you customize command line for GDB startup, use `"-quiet"` option.

If it does not, you can "customize" it with a not-so-pretty hack: move gdb executable to another file, and replace it with a shell script that will call the executable with `"-quiet"` option.

Comment: This sort jiggery-pokery would be a last resort. I worry that n months from now an update would break it after I'd forgotten what I did.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>On Mac OS X, /usr/bin/gdb happens to be a shell script.  Simply replace the two lines at the end of this file that look like</strike>

```
exec $translate_binary "$gdb" ...
```

with

```
exec $translate_binary "$gdb" -q ...
```

Modifying system files like this is probably not a very good idea, but it looks harmless enough to me.

I spoke too soon.  I just tried this out and looks like Xcode invokes the gdb binary directly (/Developer/usr/libexec/gdb/gdb-powerpc-apple-darwin on my system).  So Checkers' original suggestion is the way to go.

Comment: If there is genuinely no "safe" way to do it I would just as soon skip it.

Answer (score 0):

You may crete your own gdb wrapper, according to tip from this question:
[How to specify which GDB I can use in XCode on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668069/how-to-specify-which-gdb-i-can-use-in-xcode-on-macos)

Something along these lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Wrapped GDB executed with $@"
gdb -quiet "$@"
```

Into /usr/local/bin/mygdb with:

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXGDBPath /usr/local/bin/mygdb
```

But -quiet parameter is ignored on my 10.6.4 system anyway (XCode 3.2.3, GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1463) (Fri Mar  5 14:24:01 UTC 2010))