# How to specify which GDB I can use in XCode on MacOS

Tags: xcode, macos

How to specify which GDB (with the full path) I can use in XCode on MacOS?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the *PBXGDBPath* user default for Xcode to specify a different version of GDB for Xcode to use.

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXGDBPath <path/to/your/gdb>
```

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeUserDefaultRef/100-Xcode_User_Defaults/UserDefaultRef.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005535-CH3-SW54